# Is it possible to change the order of objects in a group?

Tags: objects, animation-nodes, groups

Simply put, is it possible to change the order of objects in a group?

I would like to change it due to using  the Animation Nodes addon effecting objects in an undesired order.

In the provided GIF, you can see that one block in the bottom left scales up at the end instead of near the beginning or so.

[image]

The Blend File:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the group (actually any list type) by using Sort List node:

[image]

Tip: You can apply multiple/cascading sorting rules to a list. For example, in my case , I first sorted all objects based on their Y location, then sorted the result again by X location.

[image]

### **Update:**

You can try applying round math here for better sorting, due to the precision, for example:

```
round(e.location.y, 3)

round(e.location.x, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, I seem to have submitted that prematurely. So far it it is really good, but there still seems to be a problem. At first, it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/29360286e6cfe4395813b98d3b767abb . But then, it seems to de-sync into this: https://gyazo.com/92d63538cf61c77f803bb1157d83a862 . Would you know why this occurs? Also, when you use e.location.x and e.location.y, are there ways to find more of these, such as for rotation, scale, and others?

Comment: It looks strange if following the way I did. I need to see how your nodetree is set up, even the scene setup. Maybe you can share the blend file here. the easiest way to find things like e.location is to hover the mouse cursor on any attribute within blender. like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OmjDX.png), or look them up on Blender API site. e is actually a defined lambda needed for python sorting, you can customize that in Advanced Setting Panel in N sidebar (usually needn't).

Comment: I've added the blend file to my original post, but here is also the link: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1854/ . And thanks for explaining how to get other things like e.location.

Comment: Oh that's because cubes in some rows or columns are not strictly aligned, though they seem so, due to the default displayed precision. Here you can use something math operations like round() to get rid off the "deviation". e.g. **round(e.location.x)**. However, I found it's not that perfect. So either you manually select a sinle row/column then scale X/Y to 0, or you create a grid array from the ground all by AN. **[Here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1863/)**  is the demo. (P.S. I used another sorting rules here, Direction, which does the same thing)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, this should be it as it seems to work beautifully now.